# права на скрипт в ubuntu из php

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, веб-программирование, bash

есть скрипт /usr/local/vesta/bin/v-add-user из под sudo работает.
его права

```
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root 5344 ноя 25 15:40 /usr/local/vesta/bin/v-add-user
```

хочу выполнить его в скрипте php , 
shell_exec('/usr/local/vesta/bin/v-add-user user pass и т.д.');

не работает...

etc/sudores

```
www-data ALL = (ALL) ALL, NOPASSWD:/usr/local/vesta/bin/*
```

не помогает я так предполагаю потому что в скрипте ещё куча обращений в другие рутовые скрипты.

как более грамотно организовать выполнение скрипта /usr/local/vesta/bin/v-add-user через web из php да еще и под root и только этот скрипт и никакой другой?

Comment: А что значит не работает?

Comment: не добавляет пользователя. если в консоли вместе с sudo то работает

Comment: А в логах что-то подозрительное есть? Если да, то добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: Вы конкретно скрипт пробовали в sudores прописать?

Comment: *хочу выполнить его в скрипте* — а скрипт от имени какого пользователя выполняется? если не от имени пользователя *root*, то он и не будет «работать» — создавать пользователей можно только от имени пользователя *root* (что и происходит с помощью программы `sudo`).

Comment: ну а если вы уже внесли необходимую конфигурацию в `/etc/sudoers`, то и используйте программу `sudo`: что-то вроде `shell_exec('sudo /ваш/скрипт параметры')`

Comment: 0xdb да, неделю смотрю эти логи и только сегодня нашел путь где должен лежать этот скрипт) Заработало)

Comment: alexander barakin спасибо, спасибо всем, проблема решена

Comment: Грамотно -- так никогда не делать.

Answer (score 1):

Можете установить пакет acl

Для CentOS

```
yum install acl
```

И установить через него права на нужный файл/директорию.
Устанавливаем маску, дефолтную маску

```
setfacl -R -m d:m:rwx,m:rwx /usr/local/vesta/bin/v-add-user
```

права для юзера apache

```
setfacl -R -m d:u:apache:rwx,u:apache:rwX /usr/local/vesta/bin/v-add-user
```

прав для юзера client

```
setfacl -R -m u:user:rwx,u:user:rwX /usr/local/vesta/bin/v-add-user
```

Answer (score 0):

> etc/sudores
>
> ```
> www-data ALL = (ALL) ALL, NOPASSWD:/usr/local/vesta/bin/*
> ```

раз необходимую конфигурацию в конфигурационный файл программы `sudo` вы уже внесли, то и используйте эту программу.

т.е., вместо:

```
shell_exec('/usr/local/vesta/bin/v-add-user user pass и т.д.')
```

указывайте:

```
shell_exec('sudo /usr/local/vesta/bin/v-add-user user pass и т.д.')
```